# How to take inputs and display their sum using stdin and stdout

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, stdin

I wrote a simple code to add two numbers with `stdin` and `stdout` to take input and display output respectively:

```
import sys
print("Inputs:")
for one in sys.stdin:
    break
int(one)

for two in sys.stdin:
    break
int(two)

three = 0

print("Output:")
three = one + two

sys.stdout.write(three)
```

The output i get is:

```
Inputs:
1
2
Output:
1
2
```

The expected output was `3`. But what I got is show in above output.

I tried the same code using `input()`:

```
one = int(input())

two = int(input())

three = one + two

print(three)
```

And the output I got was `3`. What is missing in my first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
aNumber = input('Enter a number: ')
anotherNumber = input('Enter another number: ')
print(int(aNumber) + int(anotherNumber))
```

To do this using stdin/out you can use:

```
import sys
print("Inputs:")
one = sys.stdin.readline()
two = sys.stdin.readline()
print("Output:")
three = int(one) + int(two)
four = str(three)
sys.stdout.write(four)
```

Comment: Yes. The code which you have written is same as what I want. But I want to use `stdin` and `stdout` instead of `input()`. And if I do so, the output I get is not proper as I shown in my question.

Comment: Ok. Your second code **works**. But can you tell me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: I believe it's because your variables "one" and "two" have linebreaks included on the end of them.

Comment: My code works with the following modifications: 
Instead of typecasting right after taking the input, I used your method `three = int(one) + int(two)`. 
And second thing was while displaying output, it should be in string format, while mine was in integer form.